# Java String Constructor

Tags: java, string, constructor

From the String class:

```
public String(byte[] bytes,
      int offset,
      int length)
```

Javadoc:

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified subarray of bytes using the platform's default charset.
>
> **The length of the new String is a function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the subarray.**
>
> **The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified. The CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.**

What does the bold part mean?

Comment: What do you mean? You dont understand what *decoding* is about? Or that you dont know the what *CharSet*s are about? Tried using a search engine with these terms?

Comment: The length of the new String is a function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the subarray.... What's mean??

Answer (score 3):

> The length of the new String is a function of the charset, and hence may not be equal to the length of the subarray.

In some charsets, some or even all characters use more than than a single byte. So an array of a given length may produce a shorter string. Don't assume that one byte = 1 char.

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified. The CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.

If you're decoding the string using some charset and the byte array contains a value unknown to the charset you get undefined behavior. For example if a charset uses values between 0 and 127, and your array contains the value -5 you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation

Comment: This is an additional question.
What does the subarray say?
 speak the bytes variable above?

Comment: They mean the `length` array bytes starting at `offset`. This may not be the whole array, so they call it "subarray".

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation!!